# How to make Android camera preview less lagy?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-camera

I want to make an app, which takes pictures every 0.1 second, so I made an `AsyncTask` which I execute periodically. Problem is, that the preview becomes very choppy as it stops for some time after taking each picture. This is piece of what I've got :

```
public class Photo extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            takePhoto();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            onError();
        }
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

    }

}


public void takePhoto() {

    PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            mCamera.startPreview();
            mPreview.bringToFront();


        }
    };

    mCamera.takePicture(null,null,  mPicture);

}
```

This AsyncTask takes pictures exactlz as expected, but preview is of no use, because it is extremely choppy. I also tried to start preview in `ShutterCallback`, but it only lead to appcrash.

Comment: I'm not sure that you can actually do anything about that.  It's most likely hardware related.  Have you thought about capturing video and doing something clever with the individual frames?  You'd need to force the video to be de-interlaced.  Just a thought.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to make an app, which takes pictures every 0.1 second

Few phones will support such frequent picture taking.

> the preview becomes very choppy as it stops for some time after taking each picture

AFAIK, this is unavoidable.

If the speed is that critical, you will need to limit yourself to processing preview frames using `setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer()` and a `Camera.PreviewCallback`.

Comment: OK, I could go with less frequent taking, possibly even 1 second, I will certainly try setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer() and a Camera.PreviewCallback as you suggest. Thank you !